# Ascii Conversion Program; printing error

Tags: c

I have been working on this program in C, and I don't understand why it is printing beyond the range that parameters state. here is the program, can anyone help me? Also, how do i get the input to reject numbers that arent in specified range? Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define LEN 64

int main(){

    char line[LEN];
    printf("Enter a #, 32-127: ");
    fgets(line,LEN,stdin);
    int i = atoi(line);

    printf("Enter a #, %d-127: ",i);
    fgets(line,LEN,stdin);
    int j = atoi(line);

    for(i;j;i++)
        printf("ASCII value of character %d: %c\n",i,i);

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Why are you asking for 2 numbers? If you only want to print the ascii value, why are you using a for loop? Pls explain.

Comment: This isn't causing your problem, but in C main should be declared as main(void).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand clearly what is this line doing:

```
for(i;j;i++)
```

Read more about the for-statement [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/For-Statement.html)

```
for (initialization; condition; increment){
       body
}
```

In your code, `j` is your `condition`. In **C**, `zero == false` and `different from zero is true`. Consequently, `j` never becomes zero, so the loop becomes an infinite loop.

Try to explain a little more what are you trying to achieve with the for-statement so we can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

Your "for" loop is incorrect.  Instead, try something like:

```
while ( i <= j ) {
   printf("ASCII value of character %d: %c\n",i,i);
   i++;
}
```

or

```
   for ( int idx = i; idx <=j; idx++) {
     printf("ASCII value of character %d: %c\n",idx,idx);
    }
```

For validation, just do an "if" statement, and compare the input values to whatever your validation range would be.  Leave that to you.